# file.createReadStream not support for google cloud storage image reading in nodejs

Tags: node.js, file-upload, google-cloud-storage, multipartform-data

I want to upload a google cloud storage image to a third-party API using nodejs.

I tried to upload a local disk image to third-party API, it’s working fine, and I tried cloud storage image write to the local disk, it’s also working fine.
But when I try to read cloud storage images and add them to third-party API, it's not working.

```
var fs = require('fs');
const request = require("request-promise");

async function uploadToWeChat(token){  

// this code is working fine
  const options = {
    method: "POST",
    url: `https://cors-anywhere-xbtfslevmq-km.a.run.app/https://api.weixin.qq.com/cgi-bin/media/upload?access_token=${token}&type=image`,   
    headers: {        
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
    },
    formData: {
        "image" : fs.createReadStream("temp.jpg") //upload image on localdisk
    }
};

 return await request(options, function (err, res, body) {
    if(err) console.log(err);
});
}
```

But when I am trying to upload a google cloud storage image, it's not working.

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage();
const myBucket = storage.bucket('mybucket');
const file = myBucket.file('tempImg.jpg');
const request = require("request-promise");

async function uploadToWeChat(token){
//not working
  const options = {
    method: "POST",
    url: `https://cors-anywhere-xbtfslevmq-km.a.run.app/https://api.weixin.qq.com/cgi-bin/media/upload?access_token=${token}&type=image`,   
    headers: {        
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
    },
    formData: {
      "image" :  file.createReadStream() //read stream of google cloud storage image 
  }
};

 return await request(options, function (err, res, body) {
    if(err) console.log(err);
});
}
```

I tried to access google cloud storage images and write to a local disk. It's working fine.

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage();
const myBucket = storage.bucket('mybucket');
const file = myBucket.file('tempImg.jpg');
var fs = require('fs');

   const readStream = file.createReadStream()
   var newfile = fs.createWriteStream("tempImg.jpg"); // working fine
   readStream.pipe(newfile);
```

Comment: When you say it "does not work", what actually happens? Is there an error? Is the wrong data uploaded? Does it hang/take too long?

Comment: yes, when I pass data to 'WeChat api', it gives this error as a response."{\"errcode\":41005,\"errmsg\":\"media data missing hint: [zKRdEA0384e151] rid: 60e99f38-6cbd6e2b-38f25cce\"}"

Answer (score 0):

When you upload from the filesystem, `requests` library (technically `form-data` library within it) can automatically determine file type. However when uploading a GCS stream, you will have to supply this directly:

```js
    formData: {
      "image":  file.createReadStream(), //read stream of google cloud storage image 
      options: {
        filename: 'tempImg.jpg',
        contentType: 'image/jpeg'
      }
    }
```